# I'm looking for polyline alternatives due to performance issues in google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have about 2700 markers on the map (in small area) and I'm using OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier and marker cluster.

I tried to add polylines between some of the markers. (I have parent - children relationship).

The problem is that after about 100 polylines, the map became extermaly slow, and sometimes even the tab crashes.

The connection can be static and can be only on visable area.
Do you have any suggestion to alternatives to polylines or other solution ?

Here is the code of adding polylines:

```
if (currentPoint.parentId !== "0"){
   var parentPoint = result.message[parseInt(currentPoint.parentId)];
   var coordinates = [
    {lat: parseFloat(currentPoint.latitude), lng:    parseFloat(currentPoint.longitude)},
    {lat: parseFloat(parentPoint.latitude), lng: parseFloat(parentPoint.longitude)}
    ];
var path = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: coordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
});
path.setMap(map);
```

}

p.s: I know that all the parsing operations takes resources, but I can't change the DB scheme.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you don't need to have a parent point and a current point, just keep all coordinates to one global array and keep adding them to that aray. Because it appears you don't have one polyline but a new one every time you add a coordinate.

Comment: I have an array of markers,but I need a new polyline for every current point that has a parent point.

Comment: yeah , but that's your problem. Why a new polyline every time you connect two points ? Why not one poly line that joins all connected points ? Is there any difference in appearance between one polyline that joins a series of points on a path and a seperate polyline for each pair of points on that path ? I can draw a polyline with upwards of 10 thousand points with no noticable slowing or lagging.

Comment: what you suiggest will involve changing the DB scheme (that I can't), keep children entities instead of parent entity.

Comment: you don't need to do that, you just need to check if the parent is already on a polyine, and add the child to that existing polyline instead of making a new one

Comment: I created an hashmap that holds parentid to all children including the parent. The drawing performs after the for loop, only once per chain and for 1000 markers (even less lines) is still very slow